# SPYDER: problem with plt.xlim? (data outside my axis limit are still shown)

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis, figure

This is Spyder-specific situation (on JupiterLab the code below works right).
The code below is just an example to show my problem. I want to be able to choose the data being shown in the graph. Still, when I use "plt.xlim", the data beyond my axis scale are plotted outside the plot area (see the IMAGE below).
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


A = np.linspace(1., 4., 6)
B = np.linspace(1., 20, 6)

fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (6, 5))

a1 = ax.plot(A,B, 'o', color = 'k', markersize = 5)
plt.xlim(1.2,3.9)
```

I tried to unsuccesfully add a fixed background.

```
plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (6, 5),**facecolor='lightskyblue'**)
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCHFI.jpg)

Comment: `xlim` sets the start and end of the x-axis. Change to `plt.xlim(0.2,3.9)` and try

Comment: Hi Redox, my scope is exactly to be able to scale the axis and leave some data points out. I was working with Matlab before and I never encountered such situation.

Comment: If you use another IDE like Jupyter Notebook, it does leave that point out. Perhaps something specific to Spyder then. You could filter out the values you don't want.... if that helps.

Comment: Maybe you could try `ax.set_xlim(1.2,3.9)` as you are working with matplotlib's object-oriented interface?  What exactly happened with the blue background (it is supposed to set the color of the surrounding figure)?  If you draw a line plot instead of a scatter plot, does it also draw outside the axes border?

Comment: Hi JohanC, I found the problem source being the line of code I have used in another file -- set_matplotlib_formats('svg') #display graphs in vector quality -- This line of code would propagate through all other files run in the session. By restarting Spyder and removing the code both plt.xlim(1.2,3.9) and ax.set_xlim(1.2,3.9) works well!